# Почему не работает код jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#entry").click(function () {
        $("#content_a").load("/conten.php #content_e");
        $("#entry").text("Назад");
        $("#entry").attr("id", "back");
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#back").click(function () {
        $("#content_a").load("/content.php #content");
        $("#back").text("Вход");
        $("#back").attr("id", "entry");
    });
});
```

Comment: первая часть кода выполняется а вторая нет

Comment: всем спасибо я понял вот код кому надо будет)
`$(document).ready(function(){
$("#entry").live("click", function(){
$("#content_a").load("conten.php #content_e");
$(this).text("Назад").attr("id", "back");
});

$("#back").live("click", function(){
$("#content_a").load("content.php #content")
$(this).text("Вход").attr("id", "entry")
});
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вообще по 2 раза использовать `$(document).ready(function(){`? Разве нельзя всё в одном уместить?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#entry").click(function(){
  ...
 });
 $("#back").click(function(){
  ...
 });
});
```

Вторая часть кода может не выполняться, потому что в /content.php **не найден** id="content"

Comment: но в content.php он есть

Comment: А вот это:

    $("#entry").click(function(){
     $("#content_a").load("/conten.php #content_e");
     $("#entry").text("Назад");
     $("#entry").attr("id", "back");
    });
можно заменить на:

    $("#entry").click(function(){
     $("#content_a").load("/conten.php #content_e");
     $(this).text("Назад")
            .attr("id", "back");
    });
Таким образом избавляемся от излишнего перебора элементов движком Sizzle.

Comment: спасибо))) но это пока-что не решает моей проблемы

Comment: дурацкий вопрос, но спрошу: а файл правильно вызывается, ибо в первой вызове conten.php, а во втором conten**T**.php

Comment: все правильно это два разных файла)

Comment: фторой дурацкий вопрос, раз нигде ничего не написано:  
`#back` содержится тут?

        $("#content_a").load("/conten.php #content_e");

Comment: Видимо, #back и #entry - один и тот же элемент. ID меняется скриптом.

Answer (score 1):

Вторая функция не выполняется, так как на момент ее инициализации не существует элемента к которому она должна привязаться.

Судя по первой части - пока не будет нажат определенный элемент в документе не появится элемента с id="back"  и следовательно вторая функция ни к чему не привяжется.

Обратите внимание на [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) или [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) в зависимости от версии jquery

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения а как это реализовать ?

Comment: версия qjuery последняя

Comment: $(document).on('click', '#back', function(){
$("#content_a").load("/content.php #content");
$(this).text("Вход").attr("id", "entry");
})

Вместо $(document) желательно указать какой-то родительский блок для этой кнопки поближе (по дереву). Но такой блок - который будет существовать на странице все время с момента создания.

Comment: спасибо но при клики происходит выполнения первого и сразу второго и приводит к первоначальному результату

Comment: Менять идентификаторы скриптом - неверный подход, в принципе. Используйте для этого классы.
Чтобы понять в чем ошибка нужно видеть также и HTML. Залейте все необходимое на jsfiddle, а мы посмотрим.

Comment: проблема в том что идентификатора #back нету вначале он появляться после выполнения первого клика и из за этого вторая часть неработает

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/live/

$("#entry").live("click", function(){ //...bla-bla-bla... }